# Getting value of radio button with Javascript in same HTML page

Tags: javascript

I'm new on javascript coding.

I'm kinda creating a survey page by myself. I will ask question as a 'True or False' and will get True as a 1 point, false as a 0 point. there will be multiple questions.

I tried to do it by getElementsByName but it didn't worked. my code is like that. can anyone help me please?

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" id="q1"> true
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="0" id="q1"> false
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">try</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementsByName("question1").value;
window.alert("your score is " +x);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hint: getElement **s** ByName. The method returns a *set* of elements. Have a look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName.

Comment: an ID can be shared by two or more elements in the same page. change second radio id.

Comment: Umm.. How can I get the value of 'question1'? When I use 'getElementById' it shows '1' in either way.

Comment: you need to change the `ID` of radio buttons..`ID` has to be unique. Give`q1` and `q2` as `ID's`

Comment: Okay, I got it. I changed id's as q1 and q2. But now how can I define 'x' variable as a 1 or 0 with using radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons grouped by name behave differently from `select` element, i.e. the group hasn't a single value. Also `getElementsByName()` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is an array-like object (see Felix Kling's comment).

I'd suggest you to do something like this (after giving an `id`to the `form`):

```
function myFunction () {
    var form = document.getElementById('form'), // a reference to the form element
        question = form['question1'], // creates a HTMLCollection from elements having attribute name="question1"
        n; // loop index
    for (n = 0; n < question.length; n++) { // iterates through items in HTMLCollection
        if (question[n].checked) { // checks the current item's 'checked' property
            alert("your score is " + question[n].value); // found the checked-one
            break; // "checked" found, no need to search more
        }
    }
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X767L/).

Bracket notation in `question` definition is used for future purposes. Just in case you'd have more radio button groups, which could be handled with this same function, you can pass the name of the group to function, and then use that argument within brackets instead of literal value (`'question1'`).